# multiple google maps in php loop with javascript and reference id

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps-api-3

I try to generate maps for all items in a php loop.

html:

```
<div class="container main-content">
  <!-- echo out the system feedback (error and success messages) -->
  <?php $this->renderFeedbackMessages(); ?>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Event Overview</h2>
        <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-3">
        <?php
          if ($this->events) {
            foreach($this->events as $key => $value) {
            echo 
            '
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title clearfix">
                  <b>' . htmlentities($value->event_name) . '</b> <div class="pull-right">' . htmlentities(date("d.m.y", $value->event_start_timestamp)) . ' - ' . htmlentities(date("d.m.y", $value->event_end_timestamp)) . '</div>
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="map-canvas-' . htmlentities($value->event_id) . '" onload="renderMap(' . htmlentities($value->event_id) . ', ' . htmlentities($value->google_reference_id) . ')"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ';
            }
          }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Google API Places -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

js script:

```
<script>
  function renderMap(event_id, google_reference_id) {
    var map_settings = <?php echo json_encode($this->events); ?>;

    var request = {
      reference: google_reference_id
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-'+ event_id));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(15);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

The JS is in the same php file, seperated it for better understanding. Is there an option to generate the maps in the php loop? And is the number in the unique canvas id a problem? I have a working solution with a hard coded reference and it only works with a string without numbers for document.getElementById.

Comment: What does the generated HTML for `<div id="map-canvas-' . htmlentities($value->event_id) . '" onload="renderMap(' . htmlentities($value->event_id) . ', ' . htmlentities($value->google_reference_id) . ')"></div>` look like?

Comment: `<div id="map-canvas-7" onload="renderMap(7, CqQBkQAAAJ2ovSaBhBgD-_zyhNR-T2ZzfIKlpbvRqXRYM4K2gsbKuHuGiqIYeJ8cJDmecpxjUTM28LZ3f1XmeUQXg9jxJt_sHmDmLPiWUMP9fUYUH7yyQMzeWM9GzBqRZgUs_g6ylpLBnJffvWbqTWA3ArwSeyJoSDNG7yHlsaauOW5vFIUB34l6i3Z7mDkZ0exhcQ_tMGTudsddisZ96eoT3qZfgjkSEC4k4UTdl9VEZpoK0FFewhcaFI_IrhKbeTIiOizX6HF-SkDbO8hR)"></div>`

Comment: that second parameter is a string, so it needds to be wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues with numbers in an ID

There is no `onload`-event for a div, the functions will never be called.

Possible solution:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var maps = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="map-canvas-"]');
  for(var i  =0; i < maps.length; ++i ){
    maps[i].onload();
  }
}
```

Comment: I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: the google_reference_id is a string, it has to  be enclosed by quotes

Comment: the error occurs at the closing bracket from the for loop. But added quotes to the google reference id.

Comment: youre right, sorry changed quoates to apostrophe. There is no map on the html. I try to make a fiddle to check if there is a problem with google maps and the getElementById selector.

Comment: just check http://jsfiddle.net/mnlfischer/7RrG9/ with a number it is not working. Delete the number and it works.

Comment: It's working, but you don't see it(you must change the selector in the CSS too) :http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7RrG9/1/

Comment: what an mistake. Thanks. Now I create a class to define the size. Thanks!

Comment: no need to define a class, for multiple maps you may use an attribute-selector(the same as I used with querySelectorAll): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7RrG9/2/